# Lawtex - como utilizar lógicas usando de base o campo de um Vetor de structs?

Tags: vector, lawtex

Tenho um vetor que usa uma struct com várias variáveis e uma delas é um booleano. O que posso fazer para executar algo caso ao menos um elemento desse vetor tenha essa variável como true?

```
struct[STR_Dados_dos_Inadimplentes] {
     fields {
          +[pagouMulta]: Boolean{
              name = "Pagou multa"
              request = "A multa foi paga?"
          }
     }
},

+|inadimplentes|: Vector[STR_Dados_dos_Inadimplentes]{
     name = "Dados dos inadimplentes"
     request = "Insira dados dos inadimplentes"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer executar várias lógicas, em posições e sintaxes diferentes do código, de acordo com o queira, usando o valor deste Booleano. Vou explicar 3 possibilidades de operação:

### (1) Para criação de outra variável, dentro da `struct`

Dentro de `fields`, é só usar um `if` simples para criar a lógica. Importante entender que como a variável `[pagouMulta]` já é um Booleano, você pode escrever a condição do `if` tanto como `if([pagouMulta] == true)` ou simplesmente como `if([pagouMulta])`, e a criação da nova `field` seria:

```
struct[STR_Dados_dos_Inadimplentes] {
    fields {
        +[pagouMulta]: Boolean {
            name = "Pagou multa"
            request = "A multa foi paga?"
        },
        if([pagouMulta]) {
            +[valorMulta]: Integer {
                name = "Valor da Multa"
                request = "Qual foi o valor da multa paga?"
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Então o campo `[valorMulta]`só vai existir, e ser perguntado, caso a resposta do usuário seja `true` para `[pagouMulta]`.

### (2) Para operação de alguma lógica, dentro da `struct`

Ao colocar uma lógica de operação dentro da `struct`, ela é executada com prioridade, assim que um valor dessa `struct` se altera, e vale para todos os objetos instanciados para essa `struct`, e para isso, basta criar essa lógica dentro dos `loaders`, como abaixo:

```
struct[STR_Dados_dos_Inadimplentes] {
    fields {
        +[pagouMulta]: Boolean {
            name = "Pagou multa"
            request = "A multa foi paga?"
        }
    }
    loaders {
        if([pagouMulta]) {
            //Operação específica que queira realizar, como por exemplo:
            print "A multa foi paga"
        }
    }
},
```

### (3) Para operação de alguma lógica, dentro do `operations` do `head`, `body` ou `extra`

Para usar essa variável dentro do `operations`, só é possível fazer ao usar uma variável instanciada como `STR_Dados_dos_Inadimplentes`. Então digamos que criamos uma variável 
`+<inadimplente>: STR_Dados_dos_Inadimplentes`, e queremos fazer uma operação dentro do `operations` do `head`, então podemos fazer:

```
head { 
    operations {
        if(<inadimplente.pagouMulta>){
            // Operação que queira executar, como por exemplo, usar uma branch específica para multa paga
            use branch[BRC_Multa_Paga]
        }
    }
}
```

No seu exemplo, especificamente, você criou o vetor `|inadimplentes|`, então para fazer a operação, temos duas maneiras:
1. selecionar um elemento específico do vetor, usando o índice do Vetor para selecionar um objeto específico, como `|inadimplentes{0}|` para o primeiro elemento, `|inadimplentes{1}|` para o segundo e etc, e só substituir o `if(<inadimplente.pagouMulta>)` por um `if(|inadimplentes{0}.pagouMulta|)`
2. usar um `foreach` para fazer a operação em todos os elementos do Vetor, como:

```
head { 
    operations {
        foreach(<inadimplente> IN |inadimplentes|) {
            if (<inadimplente.pagouMulta>) where (separator = "%f1, %s2, %p2 e %l2.") {
                // Operação que queira executar, como por exemplo, imprimir os dados do inadimplente
                print <inadimplente>
            }
        }
    }
}
```